# How can I call the Xabaril AddAzureBlobStorage() connecting using Managed Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, health-check

The Xabaril AddAzureBlobStorage() wants a connection string. I am connecting using Managed Identity. How can I set it up using that?

And same question for AddAzureKeyVault().